# Concatenate dicts of numpy arrays retaining numpy dtype

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, concatenation

I'm concatenating python dicts within a loop (not shown). I declare a new empty dict (dsst_mean_all) on the first instance of the loop:

```
if station_index == 0:
    dsst_mean_all = {}
    for key in dsst_mean:                        
        dsst_mean_all[key] = []               

source = [dsst_mean_all, dsst_mean]                
    for key in source[0]:
        dsst_mean_all[key] = np.concatenate([d[key] for d in source])
```

and then, as you can see in the second part of the code above, I concatenate the dict that has been obtained within the loop (dsst_mean) with the large dict that's going to hold all the data (dsst_mean_all).

Now dsst_mean is a dict whose elements are numpy arrays of different types. Mostly they are float32. My question is, how can I retain the datatype during concatenation? My dsst_mean_all dict ends up being float64 numpy arrays for all elements. I need these to match dsst_mean to save memory and reduce file size. Note that dsst_mean for all iterations of the loop has the same structure and elements of the same dtype.

Thanks.

Comment: Your description mixes up dictionaries, lists and arrays.  Are the values in `source` arrays or lists?

Comment: source is just a list of two dicts: dsst_mean_all and dsst_mean

Comment: Typically we recommend collecting all component arrays in a list, and doing concatenate once at the end.  This is usually faster  than repeated concatenates, and easier to initialize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the `dtype` of your arrays in the list comprehension.

Either hardecoded:

```
dsst_mean_all[key] = np.concatenate([d[key].astype('float32') for d in source])
```

Or dynamic:

```
dsst_mean_all[key] = np.concatenate([d[key].astype(d[key].dtype) for d in source])
```

Docs: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok one way to solve this is to avoid declaring dsst_mean_all as a new empty dict. This - I think - is why everything is being cast to float64 by default. With an if/else statement, on the first iteration simply set dsst_mean_all to dsst_mean, whilst for all subsequent iterations do the concatenation as shown in my original question.